# Border issue in IE7 for list-item for progress tracker based on pure css for cross browser support

Tags: css

I have a [working demo](http://codepen.io/siddharth-pandey/full/FGAdH) of a progress tracker based on pure css. It works fine with FF,Chrome, IE8+  but doesn't work with IE7. Seems there is a problem with border-right-style as solid in IE7 as the arrow is not shown which is rendered by div of class triangle-down.

Comment: You want arrow div insert li element, right?

Comment: Yes, in the demo above, I have spacing issue which I am not able to solve because I am using ul to make my progress tracker. When adding div which makes an arrow under li, it adds li's padding plus div's border pixels which makes the spacing of that li different then others.

Answer (score 0):

Did few changes in css

```
ul.progress-tracker div.triangle-down {
 left: -10px;
 bottom: -37px;
 margin-left: -20px;
}

.status-current{
 background: #f33738; 
}
```

Here is the [demo](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/Ljgrs)

Comment: That's great! It works very well. Also, margin property can be modified if there is a change in list item's padding or spacing of the tracker items. Thanks

Comment: There seems to be a problem with border in IE7. Do you have any fix for that?

Comment: There is still the same issue. The arrow doesn't appear in IE7 in list items but it does appear in divs.